# How to make api requests to an https server through fetch/axios react-native

Tags: android, react-native, ssl

I have set up an https server with wildcard certificates bought from Godaddy. The ssl certificates are properly installed on my server as I can access the site from the browser. Also, I have checked whether my ssl certificates were properly installed through https://www.digicert.com/help/ it shows everything is fine. Now my APIs are also hosted on this server and I need to access them from my react-native android app. The APIs are working fine if I call them from Postman but only get a 'Network failed' error upon calling from my app. I use axios as my http client for making api requests in my app.

Comment: can you please show us in code how you are accessing them? thanks. and do u have any errors in the console? try hitting the API from a web browser.

Comment: looks like your device/emulator or API server issue, not fetch/axios.

Comment: @DroiDev The code worked fine when the apis were hosted on a http server. The issue started when I made my server https from http. I tried calling a GET api from the browser and it fetches the response properly.

Comment: do you have the INTERNET permission in your manifest?

Comment: @PawełMikołajczuk The API server is working fine as I can get the response from Postman. I have worked on the same device for development and there were no issues when the apis were hosted from a http server.

Comment: @DroiDev I have the INTERNET permission in my manifest file.

Comment: is this any help for you? https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/662

Comment: @soldforapp Thanks for the link but the solutions there use nodejs core https module, which is not supported in react-native. Also, I tried calling other openly available https apis and they work properly with axios and fetch. I guess I need to configure something to make my https apis work in android. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Contact Google support and ask if you need something else. Maybe that https is on a proxy, so u might need something else. I use php to hit my https and that works fine.

Comment: i apoligize, i meant godaddy support.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have already solved the issue, but we faced a similar issue. When we dug deeper, we found that the Godaddy certificate doesn't support SNI. We found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66829184/react-native-https-api-calls-works-in-ios-but-not-working-in-android). But we reverted to the older (Lets Encrypt) certificate.